# Python Set With PYSNMP

Tags: python-3.x, snmp, pysnmp, oid

I'm trying to set a value with SNMP get. I've tested that the OID is writeable with MIB browser. I'm able to get values with another script but it doesn't make sense with a set.

```
from pysnmp.hlapi import *
engine = SnmpEngine()
community = CommunityData('public', mpModel=1)
transport = UdpTransportTarget(('target', 161))
context = ContextData()

# Your OID goes here.
identity = ObjectIdentity('.1.3.6.1.4.1.32050')

# If this was a string value, use OctetString() instead of Integer().
new_value = Integer(1)
type = ObjectType(identity, new_value)

# Setting lookupMib=False here because this example uses a numeric OID.
g = setCmd(engine, community, transport, context, identity, type, lookupMib=False)

errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = next(g)
print(errorIndication, varBinds)
```

Errors I'm seeing

```
line 17, in <module>
    errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = next(g)

pysnmp.smi.error.SmiError: ObjectIdentity object not properly initialized
```

Answer (score 1):

After you fix the problem described in previous answer, just by code inspection it screams that the OID .1.3.6.1.4.1.32050 must not be an object instance, because it is an enterprise branch. You can prove this in less than one minute by setting identity to .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0 .

Answer (score 0):

After the `context`, `setCmd` expects arguments of class `ObjectType` (i.e., couple of oid + value) which is not the case here.  It seems to me that `identity` is superfluous here.

Try this instead:

```py
g = setCmd(engine, community, transport, context, type, lookupMib=False)
```

(By the way you should avoid calling variables `type` which is a predefined python class.)